# 3 colums divs with first column dynamic width

Tags: css, layout

I have seen many examples in stackoverflow, most of them are with floats- I have a 3 column divs (dont have a parents div) - first column has dynamic width - other 2 have fixed widths - can I get a solution with out using floats - tried giving percentages, did not work - also tried using table-cell - but may be i am not using it in right way - any examples/ideas:

```
div .first{
    margin: 12px 0 5px 225px;
    width:580px;
}

div a.second{

    margin: -19px 0 5px 470px;
    display: block;
}

div a.third{

    margin: -15px 0 5px 640px;
    display: block; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="first_dynamic_width" >
        <span>abcdsef</span>
    </div> 
    <span> <a> </span> 
    <span> <a> </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use floats?  And why no container div?

Comment: I can use parent div - but if I use floats it is disturbing the whole layout down these divs, I know i could use clear float but this is coming from a separate model, that is the reason I wanted to know if there is a way without using floats?

Comment: Can you post your HTML please.  Your layout isn't making much sense to me, you have a div and two a's for your layout?

Comment: 'code'<div id="container">
   <div id="first_dynamic_width" >
     <span>abcdsef</span>
  </div>
  <span>
    <a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a>
  </span>
</div>'code'

Comment: I put your HTML in your OP.  I am actually more confused by what you are trying to do.  Why are you using <span> elements for layout?

Answer (score 0):

by using `display:block` you cannot make them side by side because the block means that it is going on the next line. Make them `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` so they can move to next to each other and then try to style them again.

Comment: How do i make the first column to expand depending on the content..?